# C: index formula for images (array), updating index in nested for loop

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, conways-game-of-life

My function accepts an array (a glider or acorn) and depicts it accurately at time zero.  However, my if/else if conditional statements counts the number of neighbors incorrectly or for some reason every index gets sent to the last else if (for indexes away from edges and corners).  Hence the number of neighbors is incorrectly counted at time 0 for index (2,3) which springs to life at time 0 +1 when it should stay dead since it only has two neighbors.
Torus topology is used (wraps around top to bottom and right to left) and here are the actual requirements:

Please Google Conway's game of life for the rules.

```
/*step 1, check whether in array[index] is 0 or 255 (color) and alter auxiliary game[index] to 1 or 0 (dead or alive).  Do this since changes need to happen simultaneously, ie. we cannot incremently change array values without having an effect on later indexes.
step 2, check neighbors for each index of game[] and alter game[] to 1 or 0 depending on rules.  
step 3, based on game[], reset array[] to 255 or 0.*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "imgops.h"

/*typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t; //for Visual Studio*/

void life(uint8_t array[],
    unsigned int cols,
    unsigned int rows)
{
    //must first scan array and set auxiliary array to alive or dead because changes happen simultaneously,
    //ie. if we change index values in array prior to scanning
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;

    int left, right, above, below, topleft, topright, botleft, botright;//life deleted
    uint8_t checkPixel;//state is for if alive/dead but now deleted

    uint8_t* game = malloc(cols*rows * sizeof(unsigned int));//allocate memory on heap for auxiliary array

                                                             //index for game array
    unsigned int index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)//go through array to check 255 or 0 and set game[] to 1 or 0
    {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            index = i + (j*cols);
            if (get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j)>0)
                game[index] = 1;
            else
                game[index] = 0;
        }
    }


    //Check neighbors 

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            index = i + (j*cols);
            //set values to 0 before checking the 8 neighbors, 1 for true 0 for false
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            above = 0;
            below = 0;
            topleft = 0;
            topright = 0;
            botleft = 0;
            botright = 0;

            //check top row, bottom row, left column, right column

            //top row but not corners
            if ((i > 0) && (i < cols - 1) && (j == 0))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)//if checkPixel is not black so alive, either 0 or 255
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }
            }

            //bottom row but not corners
            else if ((i > 0) && (i < cols - 1) && (j == rows - 1))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }

            }

            //checks left column except corner
            else if ((i == 0) && (j < (rows - 1)) && (j > 0))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }

            }

            //right column except corners
            else if ((i == cols - 1) && (j < rows - 1) && (j > 0))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }

            }

            //top left corner
            else if ((i == 0) && (j == 0))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)//if checkPixel is not black so alive, either 0 or 255
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }
            }

            //bot left corner
            else if ((i == 0) && (j == rows - 1))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, cols - 1, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }
            }

            //top right
            else if ((i == cols - 1) && (j == 0))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, rows - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }
            }

            //bottom right
            else if ((i == cols - 1) && (j == rows - 1))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }

                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }

                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }

                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }

                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }

                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }

                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }

                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, 0, 0);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }
            }

            //the other indexes not in corners nor top or bottom rows or very right or left column
            else if ((j != 0) && (j != rows - 1) && (i != 0) && (i != cols - 1))
            {
                //checks left
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j);
                //printf("%d\n",checkPixel);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    left = 1;
                }
                //checks right
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    right = 1;
                }
                //checks above
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    above = 1;
                }
                //checks below
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    below = 1;
                }
                //checks topleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topleft = 1;
                }
                //checks topright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j - 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    topright = 1;
                }
                //checks botleft
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i - 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botleft = 1;
                }
                //checks botright
                checkPixel = get_pixel(array, cols, rows, i + 1, j + 1);
                if (checkPixel > 0)
                {
                    botright = 1;
                }


            }

            //finished scanning neighbors, time to reset values of game[]
            if (game[index] == 0)//for dead cells
            {
                //exactly 3 neignbors revives a dead cell
                if (left + right + above + below + topleft + topright + botleft + botright != 3)
                    game[index] = 0;
                else
                    game[index] = 1;
            }
            else if (game[index] == 1)//for live cells
            {
                //check overcrowding and undercrowding
                if ((left + right + above + below + topleft + topright + botleft + botright == 3)
                    || (left + right + above + below + topleft + topright + botleft + botright == 2))
                {
                    game[index] = 1;
                }
                //if number of neighbors is not 2 or 3
                else
                {
                    game[index] = 0;
                }
            }

            //Reset left, right, above, below, topleft, topright, botleft, botright
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            above = 0;
            below = 0;
            topleft = 0;
            topright = 0;
            botleft = 0;
            botright = 0;


        }
    }

    //finished setting the game[]
    //alter the main array to set colors according to state
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            index = j + (i*(cols - 1));

            if (game[index] == 1)
            {
                set_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                set_pixel(array, cols, rows, i, j, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    //end of program
}
```

Comment: That is a severely over-complicated "check for neighbors" code you've written. Even if the logic were 100% correct, I'd scrap it immediately.

Comment: Also, is this C or C++? Because there are some significant refactoring advices I could give if this is meant to be C++, but it looks like you're working in pure C.

Comment: @Xirema it is C and I heard something about min and max being used but have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: step through with a debugger

Comment: @pm100 will do my best again but have gone through a few times and although I made some changes, I think it might have to do with the algorithm and not syntax.

Comment: that why i say use a debugger, a debugger helps to detect algorithm errors (the compiler detects syntax errors)

Comment: really?  I just debugged in manually by inserting printf statements and realized that the first part where I am filling the auxiliary game[] based on values of either 255 or 0 from array[] should have been a get_pixel() function call instead.  It works now up to about 30 rounds or so but then I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @pm100 making a small change to malloc solved the segmentation fault.  program is working.  btw, can you suggest a debugger to use in conjunction with sublime or another editor when I am compiling from the Linux terminal?

Comment: @NickAdoyot gdb, valgrind (only for memory), can I suggest that you self-answer your question.

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for the suggestions.  I can check off my answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Stargateur would you happen to know why the printf statements I used for debugging purposes are still being outputted to the terminal after i deleted them in the program?

Comment: Your `index` calculation is incorrect. Should be `j + cols*i` not `(col-1)`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya is it j + cols * i or i + j* cols?  I'm basing it on the formula of index = x + y * image_width where image_width is cols.

Comment: @NickAdoyot assuming j can go up to cols, it will be `j + i * cols`. If i can go up to cols, then like what you said.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya thank you for the clarification.  it is i that goes up to cols in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with all the edits, I am still getting a fail on acorn pattern initialization after only 1 round on many of the tests.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a clear description of how you think the algorithm you've implemented works. Trying to reverse engineer your thinking from the code is a slow, slow task. Additionally, your code should incorporate more comments explaining the "big picture" ideas, rather than just the little bits.

Comment: @Richard, I have three lines of comments at the beginning doing just that.

Comment: @NickAnoyot: Those are sufficient perhaps for you, but not for someone who has never looked at your code before, which is the person you should be writing comments for. You don't, for instance, describe what `array[]` and `game[]` are, what 0, 1, and 255 mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the `malloc` to the appropriate type (not `unit8_t`), and used get_pixel rather than the formula index in the first part of filling the auxiliary array.

Edited formula `index=i + (j*cols)` within every for loop and if statement to ensure consistency.

Debugged with `printf` statements inserted after initializing the `game[]` based on values from `array[].`